# Scripting downloaded programs

Tags: bash, scripts, downloads

I downloaded a game for fun and I would like to add it as part of my code for my butler program. Say I have the game moon-buggy and I would have this code run it.

```
if [ $word = "buggy" ]
then moon-buggy
# I do not know how I would run a program like this. So I just put the program name where I think it would go.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bash script uses the same syntax as the standard command line in Ubuntu. If you can launch your game with `moon-buggy` (ie, it's installed in the path), it'll work in your script.

If you've just downloaded the file (to, for example, `~/Downloads/moon-buggy`), you'll probably need to make it executable with `chmod +x ~/Downloads/moon-buggy` and in your script, you'll need to specify the path. If you're going to have multiple options a `case` is probably a better construct too.

```
case $word in
    "buggy" )
        ~/Downloads/moon-buggy
    ;;
    "anothergame" )
        ~/Downloads/anothergame
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Also this is a terminal game.